# Prove that it's a cylindrical surface(more of a factorisation question)

Tags: polynomials, analytic-geometry, factoring

Prove the equation: $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz-1=0$ describes a cylindrical surface. Now I know that an equation describes a cylindrical surface iff the LHS is a function of two first order polynomials in $x,y,z$, that is we have an equation of the form: $F(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z, a_2x+b_2y+c_2z)=0$.

I can't for the life of me factorise this(yes, i tried wolframalpha) in a meaningful way.

Comment: It is actually quite standard that $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$.

Comment: @HwChu yeah you get: $(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)-1=0$. That isnt in the form $F(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z,a_2x+b_2y+c_2z)=0$

Answer (score 1):

yeah, rotated coordinates 
$$ u = (x+y+z) / \sqrt 3 ,  $$
$$ v = (-x+y) / \sqrt 2, $$
$$ w = (-x-y+2z) / \sqrt 6 \; . $$

I get
$$  u(v^2 + w^2) = \frac{2}{\sqrt {27}} $$
For fixed $u,$ the section is a circle, but the radius shrinks as $u$ gets large. So, it is a surface of revolution around the line $x=y=z,$ but not really a cylinder

Try to get a picture of $$  z = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}  $$

Comment: Hmmm it could have actually said it's a surface of revolution. How can i show this without coordinate change(haven't touched on that)?