# Surface by revolution

Tags: analytic-geometry, surfaces

> Prove that the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3 -3xyz -1=0$ defines a surface by revolution and determine the equation for the axis of revolution.

I know I have to end up with something that looks like this:
$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=r^2$

$dx+ex+fx = g$
but I don't know where to start...

(I am aware that there is a similar question on this site but I  need a simpler answer than the one given there.)

Comment: This is the one I'm refering to. I just need a simpler answer than the one that is given there...

Comment: The equation you've written down is the equation of a sphere, not of a surface of revolution. It's hard to write something too much simpler, other than by just pulling something out of thin air. You need a way of finding the axis of symmetry; that's what is going on in that answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin I answered the same thing a couple of weeks ago. Hard to imagine how to do this without changing coordinates https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588202/prove-that-its-a-cylindrical-surfacemore-of-a-factorisation-question/2588252#2588252

Comment: I guess the answer by John Hughes at an earlier question, with some deleted comments it seems, amounts to: with constant $x+y+z = C,$ we get another constant  $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = B,$ and the intersection of the plane and sphere is a circle, a particular circle with a particular center...